What are Mirrors in maven
What actually mirrors do and use of it.
If we have a repository defined in pom.xml, before requesting to that repo does the maven checks in settings.xml, if there is any mirror of the repo then it would be fetched from mirror url. And if the artifact is not found in mirror url then does it fall back to original repo?
We have a default mirror configuration in our settings.xml file which is given below
<mirror>
  <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
  <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
  <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
  <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
  <blocked>true</blocked>
</mirror>

I am not able to understand use of this configuration

This configuration enforces security by preventing Maven from fetching artifacts from insecure HTTP repositories.
Artifacts should only be downloaded from secure https:// repositories.
It makes HTTP calls fail by pointing the mirror to a wrong address http://0.0.0.0/ and it doesn't fallback to the main origin since the property blocked is set to true.

That was great explanation, the configuration part is clear now. It is basically used to block http requests.
Can you explain the main purpose of this mirrors?
